# Verify method called in unit testing using coroutine with delay

Tags: android, unit-testing, delay, kotlin-coroutines

I've been reading [this article](https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/) to understand how to unit test a coroutine that contains a delay and applied it, but I still don't understand why `verify` is being called before having called myDelayedMethod() in the coroutine and therefore the verification fails. Isn't there a way to execute the code synchronously in the test?

Pseudocode:

```
class ClasUnderTest{

  fun method1(){
      GlobalScope.launch {
      myDelayedMethod()
    }
  }

  suspend fun myDelayedMethod(): String{
    withContext(dispatchers.default()){
      delay(X)
      ...
      someClass.someMethod()
   }
  }
}

@Test
fun myTest()= coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
  val someClassMock = mock(SomeClass::class.java)
  val myObject = ClasUnderTest(someClassMock) 
  method1()
  verify(someClassMock).someMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea could be to return the `Job` in `method1` like the following:

```
fun method1(): Job {
  return GlobalScope.launch {
    myDelayedMethod()
  }
}
```

And then replace `method1()` with `method1().join()`, so that `runBlockingTest` waits for the execution of the coroutine.

Comment: I tried but I obtaining an exception informing that "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet"

Comment: This worked besides of making sure that code to be tested uses   TestCoroutineScope() as  CoroutineContext and TestCoroutineDispatcher as  Dispatcher.